# Autonúmerico en un array hecho con numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Quiero exportar una serie de variables a un archivo .txt desde un array de numpy. Me gustaría que en él .txt, cada fila tuviera asociado un número empezando por el 1 en orden ascendente hasta llegar al final. He estado buscando si hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde la orden np.savetxt pero no lo encuentro.

El código que utilicé para exportar mis datos es:

```
if cont==0:

        Resultados=np.array([i,j,xc,yc,200*r],ndmin=2) (cont)
    else:
        ResultadosAux=np.array([i,j,xc,yc,200*r],ndmin=2)
        Resultados=np.append(Resultados,ResultadosAux,axis=0)
    cont= cont+1

 print(cont)
    print(Resultados)
    np.savetxt('C:\Python\Resultados_final.txt', Resultados, fmt='%f',delimiter=',',header="muestra,seccion,xc,yc,ancho",comments='')
```

Por lo que consigo un .txt con las variables que quiero pero sin que las filas estén numeradas. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres agregar un índice a las fila  `numpy.savetxt` no ofrece ninguna opción para ello. Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una nueva columna con el rango:

```
import numpy as np


# Array ejemplo de partida
resultados = np.array([[4.2, 13.2, 5.2, 1.3, 8.6],
                       [5, 8.3, 43.5, 4.2, 2.3],
                       [47.3, 23.5, 7.23, 5.21, 81.2]]
                      )

out = np.insert(resultados, 0, np.arange(1, resultados.shape[0] + 1), axis=1) 
np.savetxt('C:/Python/Resultados_final.txt', out,
           fmt=('%d', '%f', '%f', '%f', '%f', '%f'), delimiter=',', 
           header=",muestra,seccion,xc,yc,ancho", comments=''
           )
```

Esto generará un archivo como el siguiente:

> ,muestra,seccion,xc,yc,ancho
>   1,4.200000,13.200000,5.200000,1.300000,8.600000
>   2,5.000000,8.300000,43.500000,4.200000,2.300000
>   3,47.300000,23.500000,7.230000,5.210000,81.200000

---

> **Nota:** Nunca uses la barra inclinada inversa en cadenas que especifican rutas sin escapar. El carácter `\` es usado para identificar secuencias de escape (`\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `\U`, etc). Escapa siempre la barra `'C:\\Python\\Resultados_final.txt'` o usa la barra inclinada que es universal 
>   `'C:/Python/Resultados_final.txt'`.

Comment: Es justo lo que quería, muchas gracias :) tengo en cuenta tu nota.

Comment: Quería crear una columna nueva con un código de cada registro que fuera la concatenación del valor de la columna "muestra" y de la columna "sección" separadas por un guión bajo. He estado mirando la orden numpy.concatenate pero no parece que sirva para concatenar columnas dentro del .txt sino más bien arrays, ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Deva ten en cuenta que eso implica usar una cadena para la columna y los arrays NumPy solo pueden tener un tipo de dato. Si bien es cierto que se puede usar arrays estructurados creo que deberías considerar usar [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), que usando NumPy por debajo es mucho más potente y flexible para este tipo de cosas, además de tener un soporte verdadero a csv a la hora de importar y exportar..